# Передача значений через ссылку

Tags: php

Есть ссылка и input

```
<a href="http://test1.ru/panel?id=2&m=1&count=" style="color: rgb(70,130,180)">Перевод монет</a><input type="text">
```

Как значение из input засунуть в ссылку (в count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут тебе скорее js нужен

http://jsfiddle.net/xFqW4/

Я многих моментов не предусмотрел, но идея такова

P.S. Можно также разбивать строку запроса методом split и последний элемент массива обрабатывать